# jquery attribute selector problem: Dynamic attribute selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is here

```
$("a[href=$.jqURL.url()]").hide();
```

`$.jqURL.url()` return current page url.

But this code don't work

Is it possible to select dynamically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to build the selector as a string:

```
$("a[href=" + $.jqURL.url() + "]").hide();
```